# Have you ever log into Bigquery from South Korea with a EU or UK account?

Tags: authentication, google-bigquery

If anyone can help, it would be massively appreciated. Do you know if it is possible to log into Bigquery from South Korea using a EU or UK account?

Thanks
Diego

Comment: Is there something you expect the user to see in this specific scenario? Are you looking for something new, like unusual behavior from a recent system change?

Comment: I would not expect any problem

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response!! This is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any issue that you would use either a EU or UK account to log into the BigQuery from South Korea.